# How to remove line breaks inside a specific element using JSOUP

Tags: jsoup

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function answer1()
{
alert("This answer is incorrect. " +
"The value returned by SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects the most recently "+ 
" executed implicit cursor. Because a row was inserted by the procedure, this attribute returns 1. " );
}

function answer2()
{
alert("This answer is incorrect. " +
"The value returned by SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects the most recently executed implicit cursor. In this case, it should be fairly obvious: I"+ 
" insert a row and then call SQL%ROWCOUNT. “Last Count=1” is displayed. " );
}

function answer3()
{
alert("This answer is correct. " +
"The update changes no rows, because the table is currently empty. The insert procedure does not" +
" perform an insert. So the call to SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects the impact of the update: 0 rows updated. " );
}

function answer4()
{
alert("This answer is correct. " +
"No rows are modified, because the WHERE clause specifies ID = 0. But no error is raised, so the "+ 
"next statement is executed and SQL%ROWCOUNT is set to 0. " );
}
</script>
```

When I am doing html paring I'm getting  tag in place of line breaks like the below html

```
"<script type="text/javascript"><br/>function answer1()<br/>{<br/>alert("This answer is incorrect. " +<br/>"The value returned by SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects the most recently "+ <br/>" executed implicit cursor. Because a row was inserted by the procedure, this attribute returns 1. " );<br/>}<br/>function answer2()<br/>{<br/>alert("This answer is incorrect. " +<br/>"The value returned by SQL%ROWCOUNT reflects the most recently executed implicit cursor. In this case, it should be fairly obvious: I"+ <br/>" insert a row and then call SQL%ROWCOUNT. “Last Count=1” is displayed. " );<br/>}<br/></script>"
```

I just want to remove this br tag using jsoup. Can i get some suggestion about the above mentioned issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Jsoup to get the outer html of the script tag and then manually remove the `<br/>` tags with String replacement.

```
Element scriptElement = document.select("script").first();

String scriptHtml = scriptElement.outerHtml();

String htmlWithoutBr = scriptHtml.replaceAll("<br/>", "\n");
// or if you don't need to preserve the line breaks use below
// String htmlWithoutBr = scriptHtml.replaceAll("<br/>", " ");
System.out.println(htmlWithoutBr);
```